# Do you need to subquery every time you create a new column and want to use it in the WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Do you need to subquery every time you create a new column and want to use it in the WHERE statement?

Ex. I want to create a new column called "Lag" that takes the column `login_date` and lags it by 4 days. Is there a way to filter the table by that column immediately, or do I always need to create a subquery to use WHERE on the new column "Lag".

This would be the ideal:

```
SELECT id,
login_date,
LAG(login_date, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY login_date) as Lag
FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(Lag, login_date) = 4
```

This is the way that I'm trying to avoid:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM
    (SELECT id,
    login_date,
    LAG(login_date, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY login_date) as Lag
    FROM table ) sub
WHERE DATEDIFF(sub.lag, sub.login_date) = 4
```

Comment: yes, you need a subquery or common table expression to use an expression containing a window function in a where condition.  why do you want to avoid it?  if you explain why, someone may be able to come up with something that helps you

Comment: `WHERE login_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY`

Comment: @RickJames 4 rows <> 4 days

Comment: Show some sample data -- input and output.

Comment: Reasons: 1) Convenience 2) Readability 3) Speed(?)
But mainly convenience. Its nice to create 3 different columns and then filter using WHERE immediately. No worries if this cant be done and we must use a subquery to do this, just wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

A clarification would be that you can't refer to a column alias in the WHERE clause of the same query that defined the alias. That's why we have to put the query into a subquery or a common table expression, and refer to the alias in the outer query.

Comment: Gotcha, so it is impossible to create a column and immediately use a WHERE statement on it in the same table.

Comment: That is correct.